# Can't authenticate username with password in MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongodb and I have a bug in authenticating the username and password in mongodb with java. Can anyone tell me the correct source code to connect mongodb with java? Currently I have an error in getdb

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;  

public class Javamongodbconnection {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {       
      try{          

         MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
         DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "company" );
         System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
         boolean auth = authenticate("Dell", "syzygy");
         System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);

      } catch(Exception e){
         System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the exception? If the problem is at getDB, that means that the problem is before you try to authenticate. And what is the "authenticate" method?

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the credentials before you try to getDB...

```
private void main() {
    try {
        ArrayList<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<>();
        credentials.add(MongoCredential.createCredential("username", "company", "password".toCharArray()));

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), credentials);
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("company");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
        //boolean auth = authenticate("Dell", "syzygy");
        //System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```